# \includeonly not including parts correctly because of _ in the file name and breqn

Tags: include, breqn

I am trying to use

```
\include{...}
```

and

```
\includeonly{...}
```

to structure my thesis and faster compile the document. As long as I only use `\include{...}` everything works fine. But once I try to use `\includeonly{...}` in the preamble I only get the table of contents, the list of figures and tables and the Bibliography but no actual content. I don't know what I am doing wrong. I tried to remove some packages I am using but so far I couldn't find one that causes the problem. In case it matters every "part" consists of `\chapter{...}` parts, `\section{...}`and `\subsection{...}` parts including text, tables and figures. Here is what I have in my main document (I left the whole preamble in case one of the packages I use causes the problem):

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,DIV=10,BCOR=0.5cm]{scrreprt} 
\usepackage[german, english]{babel}
\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{Pictures/}}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{textgreek}
\usepackage[toc,page]{appendix}
\usepackage{sidecap}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{breqn}
\usepackage{tabularx}
\usepackage{tabu}
\usepackage[font=small,format=plain,labelfont=bf,up,textfont=it,up]{caption} 
\usepackage{fixltx2e}
\linespread{1}



\includeonly{part_1}




\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{headings}


\include{titlepage}


\setcounter{page}{0}

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables




\include{abstract}



\pagenumbering{arabic}

\include{part_1}

\include{part_2}

\include{part_3}




\bibliography{thesis.bib}{}
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}



\end{document}
```

After some try and error I found an answer:

There seems to be an issue with using _ in file names when using `\includeonly`.
By using only file names without `_`, like `part1` or `part-1` everything seems to work fine. Strangely there are documentations about `\include` and `\includeonly` that use _ in their file names like this one here:
http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/LaTeX/Modular_Documents

Comment: You have to use `\includeonly` in conjunction with `\include` - they are not exclusive. So use `\includeonly` in the preamble and `\include` in the document body. The file(s) mentioned in `\includeonly` should also be contained in some `\include` command.

Comment: @David Carlisle: I don't get any error just a lot of warnings like this:"pdfTeX warning (dest): name{table.caption.8} has been referenced but does not e
xist, replaced by a fixed one"

regarding your second comment: I don't have any nested include parts if you mean that. The only thing I include in the separate parts are graphics.

Comment: @Werner: I think did that as you can see in the example text.

Comment: @David Carlisle: To generate the example I changed the names of my files from PhD_thesis_partx to partx but I haven't actually tried that code until now. Now that I tried it I figured out that once I use names without _ it works fine. Strangely \include accepts names containing _ but \includeonly does not. Can that actually be the case?
It is correct that when I use \includeonly that only that part is displayed and the rest not right. Do you know if there is also a way to display the other parts but not compile them?

Comment: @Marty (a) you should _always_ test the posted code:-) (b) `_` should work in filenames. (b) `includeonly` does only process the named bits but uses the aux file of the others so numbering is right. pdftex can only make a single pdf file so you have to make all the chapters shown. It is possible to process parts as single documents. (c) when i started using TeX is was common to take 15 minutes per page on PCs. I would guess it doesn't take that long to process your entire thesis even without `\includeonly` :-)

Comment: @David Carlisle: (a) I usually know I just didn't think that could make difference, sorry for that. (b) `_` should work but I tested it now several times and it seems to be the problem. (c) it only takes 1 minute in total but as often I compile it it makes a big difference :). with 15min per page I think I would never finish my thesis... good thing PCs got faster :).
Thanks for your help!

Comment: Hey you edited the question thanks. So I deleted my last comment. I can reproduce the effect. That's strange, back in a bit....

Comment: @David Carlisle: It seems the `breqn` package in combination with `\includeonly` and `_` seems to cause that bug. Damn that was hard to find. I thought I tried that out before but now it seems reproducible, at least for me. Could you try that as well?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's `breqn`.

Making your example a bit more minimal

```
\documentclass [a4paper,12pt,DIV=10,BCOR=0.5cm]{scrreprt} 

\usepackage{cite}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}

\usepackage{breqn}

\linespread{1}



\includeonly{part\string_1}




\begin{document}

\pagenumbering{Roman}
\pagestyle{headings}



\include{part\string_1}

\include{part\string_2}



\end{document}
```

If you comment out `breqn` it works without the `\string` with `breqn` you need to make a safe `_`.